# Installing nvm using Makefile

Tags: shell, make, node.js

I've set up a Makefile like the following:

```
NVM := $(shell command -v nvm 2> /dev/null)

setup:

ifndef NVM
    @echo "Installing NVM"
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
    nvm install node
endif

# do setup here
```

My goal is to install nvm if not already. Every time I run `make setup` the script enters nvm installation, **even if nvm is already installed**. In fact, if in a new Terminal I run `command -v nvm` I see:

> nvm

Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

The NVM `install.sh` script by default installs to `~/.nvm`. It does not install an actual binary or script named *nvm*. Instead the *nvm* command is a function defined in `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` which is sourced from the interactive terminal profile (e.g., `~/.bashrc`). A simple way to test for the installation of NVM is to check for the presence of the sourced file.

```
NVM := $(shell test -f "$(HOME)/.nvm/nvm.sh"; echo $$?)

setup:

ifneq ($(NVM),0)
        @echo "NVM not installed"
else
        @echo "NVM installed"
endif
```

Note that we're storing the exit code in *NVM*. *0* means it was found.